Strange output in VS Code Python console
When I execute even the simplest Python script in the VS Code I receive strange output in the console. Some hashes and part of paths are also printed. Let's say the script is just:
print("HELLO")

the output of it is:
PS C:\Users\Z0176880\LEARNING\Workshop>  & 'c:\Users\Z0176880\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Z0176880\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.5.11001012-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '50528' '--' 'C:\Users\Z0176880\LEARNING\Workshop\a.py'
HELLOb62ugpy\x5clauncher' '50528' '--' 'C:\x5cUsers\x5cZ0176880\x5cLEARNING\x5cWorkshop\x5ca.py' ;e469fac6-924c-465f-b7a5-951a6eb7bb62

in the IDE it looks like that:

if I execute this script with Python in CMD it works as expected - only HELLO is printed. I tried VS Code reinstallation but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

What does your launch config look like?

For those who are interested in this issue - most likely it is related to the latest VC Code version (1.88) - I installed the previous one downloaded from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_87 and in this one, such error does not occur.
